# Why are autotyped variables throwing an attribute error? QGIS python plugin using PyDev, Eclipse 4.4, OSX 10.9.3

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, qgis

First Q, I have searched here and the GIS Stackexchange for quite a while but to no avail.

I am trying to implement an if statement in my plugin.py, with the condition being whether a check box is ticked.  plugin.py imports a class from dialog.py, which in turn imports a class from interface.py which contains the variable representing the checkbox.  The line currently causing the QGIS error is as follows:

```
QObject.connect(self.dlg.ui.writeFileCheck,SIGNAL("stateChanged(int)"),self.changeActive)

AttributeError: 'Ui_ImportHXLDialogBase' object has no attribute 'writeFileCheck'
```

It is the:

```
self.dlg.ui.someCheckbox.isChecked()
```

type of commands that keep causing the problems - I have tried to copy various implementations of boxes and buttons from other plugins but I keep getting this error.  What's strange is that the whole string autocompletes in Eclipse so I presume it can't be a syntax or spelling issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not enough to know what's happening -- what it says is that the writeFileCheck attribute wasn't created, so, maybe you needed to call a method to properly create your UI so that you have that attribute?

Comment: Thanks - I restarted from scratch and the problem didn't recur so I still have no idea what was wrong!